# Finish work item from "Work items" list in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

When I have the list view of work items which will show if I click "Work items", how do I change state of a work item or view comments? Work items seem to not be draggable. There seems to be no dropdown to use to change the state. The comments speech bubbles seems to not be clickable.

Menu:

[image]

View:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is really a simple one. You should double click on a work item so that you will able see all the details in it. Along with the details you can view comments. On the top right corner you can see a drop down for state, through which you can change the state.

Comment: If I double click a work item, the list view is lost. The dropdown does not contain the states you see in the "Sprints" page.

Comment: ohh, but in this case the drop down should be exactly same as the one in sprint page.

Comment: Ah, I see now that custom states do not show up in the dropdown.

Comment: But that fact that I cannot see the listview all the time is a problem in itself.

Comment: There is a customize option at the top where in you can add fields which you want in the list view. That may help...

Comment: this answer is correct. maybe I'm old fashioned but that was totally not intuitive. none of that looks editable.  Thank you for pointing us in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You have there different views. Boards is like a Kanban - you can there chanage a state by drag and drop to different columns. But you will not be able there to see comment wihtout going inside.

Sprints is kind iof similar but introduce context of sprint. So you have timeline with columns representing states for given timebox/sprint.

Use this view which works best for you, but try and check as this is the best way to learn it.

Comment: I prefer a list view because items can be arranged in priority order.